# Trying to call Java code from Google App Engine i get errors?

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I have java classes that I call from my html file using this ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://www.verifiedalerts.appspot.com/verifiedalert?action=addIntrusionRules",
        dataType:"text",
        async:false,
        data:   "params=" + objStr,
        success: function(data){
                          //alert(data);
            }
        });
```

when I see the log I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
```

but when I run another similar file from a different computer it works somehow and now it is not working.

Does someone know how to get past this?

Comment: Is there any PHP involved? I only ask because you tagged it as such.

Comment: well the file is a php file.. i mean that was a complete waste of comment space dont you think..

Comment: No reason to get irritated. I was just trying to garner a more complete picture of your situation. You're asking for free help from volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring on the server, so we really need to see the App Engine code and the complete stacktrace of the exception to tell you anything useful. One thing that's immediately noticeable is that you're referring to "www.verifiedalerts.appspot.com" when you should probably be referring to "verifiedalerts.appspot.com" - the former may or may not work depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it has to do with [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The same origin policy prevents a
>   document or script loaded from one
>   origin from getting or setting
>   properties of a document from another
>   origin. This policy dates all the way
>   back to Netscape Navigator 2.0.

You might find these threads useful to workaround that:

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- [Why same origin policy for XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830050/why-same-origin-policy-for-xmlhttprequest)